# Azure WebApp and parsing Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a classic situation - client need to have ability for upload excel file and application should parse it. There are many tools for parsing excel file, but all of them need to add reference to excel library.

I have to publish this project to Azure Web Application and don't want to install anything there. Any way to parse excel file with minimum references?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing an excel file and reading a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044835/parsing-an-excel-file-and-reading-a-cell)

Comment: If you want to parse excel you need to install a parser. Alternatively you could let them export the excel as tab seperated and parse that as a normal text file

Comment: In azure, I suggest use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader), which supports .xls and .xlsx file. You can also refer to my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189639/recommended-way-to-read-data-from-an-excel-file-using-an-azure-app-service/53203279#53203279)

Comment: Oleg, have you resolved your issue?

Comment: And if it's not resolved, could you please let us know where you upload your excel file to? blob storage or somewhere?